# Get x-axis values of selected graphs

Tags: highcharts

How to display highlighted graph's x-axis values only , on bar graph in
high chart?I have 6 graphs plotted, need to highlight selected graphs x-axis values only.

```
xAxis: {
      categories: userArr,
      title: {
            text: 'Users'
        },
  },
```

Comment: You want to get the value or highlight it?:

Comment: I have given x-axis as array, but the x-axis is not displaying, instead og usernames it is displaying numbers.Also on click legend, the xaxis is not changing also.

Comment: Could you recreate issue on jsFiddle? Maybe your `userArr` is empty array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do so by using formatter function in datalabel ([See Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/hm2h53o3/4/))

```
     dataLabels: {            
        formatter: function(){
        return this.point.name
        },
            enabled: true
          }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this is displaying names in bar.I need to display corresponding users of graph in x-axis.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle with the problem so that we could provide solution fpr exact issue.

Comment: if I uncomment formatter function John and Jane are visible on series bars  .... bar: {
              dataLabels: {            
            formatter: function(){
            return this.point.series.name
            },
                enabled: true
              }
            }     What exactly you want to show on bars ?

Comment: in the fiddle i have given static array, suppose if i both names and data to an array say, series[] and if i place that array in series it will not work.Also i need to display the usernames of users whose the graph is displayed

Comment: Ok , So to create dynamically thats not working.. Check > is your category array is an array of string? it expects array of string . OR if you could take a minute to post your JSON data (response which is coming dynamically) would be great

Comment: i donot want to display usernames in bars.need to display in x-axis (here y-axis)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic/ .here in the place of countries i need to display usernames whose graph is displayed only.

Comment: no, here the name is displayed in graph no?i want it as x-axis labels like countries displayed in http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic/

Comment: can anybody please help me out of this?